Expected "gap" when applying rearrangement inequality to order statistics
This is a small, self-contained problem that I came across while deriving a competitive ratio in my research. Order statistics are not my area of expertise --- if anyone is familiar with prior work or relevant bounds to look into, it would be much appreciated!

Problem.

Consider a sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ and its corresponding order statistics $X_{1:n} \leq \dots \leq X_{n:n}$ drawn from a distribution over [0,1] with known mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2 > 0$. Find some lower-bounding function $f$ such that
$$(\star) :=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1) \cdot (\mu - X_{n-i+1:n})\right]  \geq f(n, \mu, \sigma) > 0.$$

Intuitively, $f$ measures the impact of weighting the largest values of the sample the least vs weighting them based on an arbitrary ordering, in terms of the sample size and the underlying distribution.

Motivation.
It can be shown using the rearrangement inequality that $(\star) > 0$ w.h.p. in the number of samples. The inner sum has the form $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$ where $a_i = i-1$ and $b_i = \mu - X_{n-i+1:n}$ are both increasing sequences. So, any rearrangement (and in particular the original sample order) of the sequences provides a lower bound:
$$(\star) \geq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1) \cdot (\mu - X_i)\right] = 0.$$
The inequality is strict when $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are not in decreasing order.

Approach. After a lot of searching, I found these results on upper bounds for the first moment of order statistics:
(Arnold and Groeneveld) $$\mathbb{E}[X_{k:n}] \leq \mu + \sigma \sqrt{\frac{k-1}{n-k+1}}$$
(Gribkova) $$\mathbb{E}[X_{k:n}] \leq \mu \cdot 2e^{-13/6} \cdot g^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right) \text{ for } g(u) = u(1-u)$$
The first is very general and, unfortunately, too loose to be useful in this case. I'm not sure I understand the notation used in the second -- is there a convention that I'm not aware of when using $g^{-1}$ in this way?

There's a way to reduce the question from considering $n$ samples to just considering $2$ samples. This results in a pretty simple exact formula in terms of the distribution's CDF and CCDF. This isn't exactly what you asked for, but maybe it will work as a first step, or maybe it will suffice for your downstream application.
First, because I kept losing track, I'm going to write $X_{-i:n}$ to mean the $i$th smallest sample, i.e. $X_{-i:n} = X_{n - i + 1:n}$.
The main idea is to write the sum you're trying to bound as a sum over all pairs of indices. Observe that for any realization of the samples,
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i = 1}^n (i - 1) X_{-i : n}
&
= \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1} X_{-i: n}
& &\text{[write $i - 1$ as a sum]}
\\ &
= \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1} \min\{X_{-i : n}, X_{-j : n}\}
& &\text{[because $X_{-i : n} \leq X_{-j : n}$]}
\\ &
= \sum_{\substack{\{i, j\} \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}}} \min\{X_{-i : n}, X_{-j : n}\}
& &\text{[it's a sum over unordered pairs]}
\\ &
= \sum_{\substack{\{i, j\} \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}}} \min\{X_i, X_j\}
.
& &\text{[still summing over all pairs]}
\end{aligned}$$
So, by linearity of expectation,
$$
\mathbb{E}\Bigl[\sum_{i = 1}^n (i - 1) (\mu - X_{-i : n})\Bigr]
= \binom{n}{2} \bigl(\mathbb{E}[X_1] - \mathbb{E}[\min\{X_1, X_2\}]\bigr).
$$
The question thus boils down to how much the mean of a single sample compares to the mean of the minimum of two i.i.d. samples.
There's a nice representation of this quantity when sampling from nonnegative distributions. Writing $\bar{F}(t) = \mathbb{P}[X_1 > t]$ for the CCDF of the distribution, the tail integral formula for expectation implies
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[X_1] &= \int_0^\infty \bar{F}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
, \\
\mathbb{E}[\min\{X_1, X_2\}] &= \int_0^\infty \bar{F}(t)^2 \, \mathrm{d}t
,
\end{aligned}$$
which means
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_1] - \mathbb{E}[\min\{X_1, X_2\}]
= \int_0^\infty \bigl(\bar{F}(t) - \bar{F}(t)^2\bigr) \, \mathrm{d}t
= \int_0^\infty F(t) \, \bar{F}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
,
$$
where $F(t) = 1 - \bar{F}(t)$ is the CDF. So an exact expression for the quantity of interest is
$$
\mathbb{E}\Bigl[\sum_{i = 1}^n (i - 1) (\mu - X_{-i : n})\Bigr]
= \boxed{\binom{n}{2} \int_0^\infty F(t) \, \bar{F}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.}
$$
(You can of course change the $\infty$ limit to $1$ if the support is $[0, 1]$, but this works for general nonnegative distributions. I think it might even work for general distributions if you make the lower limit $-\infty$, but I haven't checked this carefully.)
This settles how your answer should scale as a function of $n$. As for $\mu$ and $\sigma$, I'm not 100% sure whether there are uniform bounds. You could try using Chebyshev's inequality to bound $F(t)$ and $\bar{F}(t)$. But it's possible that for any fixed $\mu$ and $\sigma$, there's a way to make the quantity arbitrarily small.
